# ios8 searchController searchResults custom cell is wrong height

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, uisearchcontroller

I'm using an [Apple sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014683) as a guide to building a searchController scheme. Everything is working, except I cannot figure how to set the height of the SearchResultsController cell.

The main tableview and the search results table both point to the same Nib. The colors, fonts and font sizes are ok. The height of the main table view is ok.

Both controllers point to a custom nib that has two labels. Below are some images and code snips.

Any help (things to check?) would be appreciated..

custom nib:

[image]

Here's the code for the cellAtIndexPath for both controllers (I've omitted font, and color info:

```
main controller:
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    StationCell *cell = (StationCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kStationCellIdentifier];

    currentStationArray = stationListArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.stationLabel.text = [currentStationArray valueForKey:@"Name"];

    NSString *tempString = [currentStationArray valueForKey:@"LineCode1"];

    cell.lineLabel.text = tempString;

    return cell;
}

search result controller:
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    StationCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kStationCellIdentifier];

    currentStationArray = [self.selectedStations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.stationLabel.text = [currentStationArray valueForKey:@"Name"];

    cell.stationLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OrdredeDepart" size:24];
    cell.stationLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    NSString *tempString = [currentStationArray valueForKey:@"LineCode1"];

        cell.lineLabel.text = tempString;


    return cell;
}
```

Finally, the main cell looks like this:

[image]

and the search results cell, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 80.0f;
}
```

Comment: I tried that. It's not effective. other ideas welcome and welcome to SO.

Comment: did you set your tableView.delegate to self?

Comment: It would be great if you could look at the Apple sample in the link above. I have checked and double checked that the data sources and delegates conform with the sample.

Comment: You know what - your answer was spot on. I tried again, by putting the cell height in the main controller, and it worked. I'm really grateful.

Comment: Yes, you should put it on the controller where you put your tableview. No problem :)